# Increase text size in list display

Tags: nautilus, fonts

In List display text size is much smaller than icon size. With very small zoom (30%) text proportion looks good to me, although everything is too small ;-) then increasing size, text size lags size of icons! I really need larger text. Any tweak for nautilus text and its scaling relative to icon size please?

Comment: Screenshot? What version of nautilus (`nautilus --version` in terminal), what have you tried (tweaking systems font sizes, etc)...

Comment: same here: GNOME nautilus 3.10.1 on 14.04

Comment: On 14.04 the scale of Ubuntu system works for Nautilus (might need to reboot to get it picked-up)

Answer (score 0):

I had large text all tuned for a media centre that's a distance away.

Today I opened Nautilus to find same thing, icon's huge, text tiny, no matter what I set Universal Access or zoom to.

After a full restart it's back to responding.

I've NEVER run into this in any version previous to 14.04. Perhaps due to a recent update?

Anyhow, try Universal Access settings if you haven't yet. If no effect, restart and try again.